# Platform Event Limits regarding CometD and non-CometD clients

Tags: platform-event, jsforce, cometd

As per the Salesforce Documentation regarding Platform Event limits,

> in Performance or Unlimited Editions of Salesforce, maximum number of
>   delivered event notifications within a 24-hour period, shared by all
>   CometD clients is 50,000, while the maximum number of event
>   notifications published per hour is 250,000.

It also says that

> Non-CometD clients, including Apex triggers, processes, and flows,
>   don’t count against the event delivery limit.

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Does this mean that the maximum number of delivered event notifications within a 24-hour period, shared by all **non-CometD** clients is 250,000?
2. What about a node application where I have used jsForce library to subscribe to the events, is it a **CometD** client?
3. Are there any other non-CometD clients other than mentioned above?

Comment: for 1 - don't you mean 250,000 per hour?